# Как лучше считывать такие числа по средствам java из строки?

Tags: java, format

**Ниже приведен формат.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть строки такого вида:

`0.0-2.013896591961E-04-1.136868377216E-12` (3 числа)

`6.356909871101E-04-2.046363078989E-12` (2 числа)

Как из них можно считать число?
Есть ли какой-то встроенный метод **java**, который парсит такие строки? 
Или только вручную это можно сделать с помощью, например, регулярных выражений?

Comment: В примере написаны числа без пробелов. Может это опечатка и между числами нужны пробелы? Тогда можно просто вначале разбить строку на числа строковые используя пробел для разбиения, а потом распарсить просто как обычные дробные числа используя `Float.parseFloat("-1.136868377216E-12")`.

Comment: Если числа склеены без пробелов то в большинстве случаев нельзя однозначно узнать что там за числа, например два числа `-1.2E-0451.234`, можно разбить как `-1.2E-04` и `51.234`, а также `-1.2E-045` и `1.234`

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul к сожалению, они склеены если были бы не склеены то я бы не задавал тут вопросов, но эти числа в строке записаны по формату, то есть таких случаев, которые вы описали не будет.

Comment: А можно кусок кода который форматировал числа? Тот пример неоднозначности разбиения что я написал выше актуален всегда даже если по формату сделали, т.к. там размер экспоненты может быть как 1 так и 2 и 3 значный и все эти размеры валидные и могут создаться при форматировании. Другое дело если экспонента всегда 2 знака считать, то ещё можно числа тогда разбить, но только если все числа в одном формате. Например если два числа вида `12.34` и `56.78` склееть то будет `12.3456.78` и их можно легко напутать с `12.345` и `6.78`, причём судя по вашему примеру `0.0` такое может быть

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul в этом коде нет ничего интересного, я числа считываю из файла и в этом файле числа уже склеены. Есть только документация с форматом и все

Comment: Ну вот как раз документация с форматом и могла бы пригодиться, можете её в вопросе процитировать? Если там чётко оговорены правила по которым форматируются числа, тогда ещё можно декодировать их, а если там просто как угодно выводили числа под ряд тогда конечно будет неоднозначность.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul обновил вопрос

Comment: Не ясно описание формата, в нём какие то буквы I, X, F, D используются, что они обозначают? Есть ли где-то точное описание что означают буквы, а также что означают числа стоящие справа от этих букв, что означают точки и запятые. Кстати в формате похоже между каждым числом написана запятая, или это запятая не выводится а просто разделяет несколько описаний формата?

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul смысле что? это описание формата. Я вижу вы мне тут не поможете

Comment: Ну если нет подробностей то можно просто попробовать регулярное выражение например `\-?\d+\.\d+(?:E[\-\+]\d{2})?`

Comment: Вот я на вашем примере прогнал регулярное выражение, [посмотрите тут](https://regex101.com/r/zrUNuu/1), справа Match Information выводит 3 успешных захвата трёх чисел.

Comment: Как вариант - написать regex для формата числа с плавающей точкой и по нему искать в строке. Нашел, вырезал, еще раз начал искать, пока не найдем.

Comment: ну вот и привели б регулярку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать для захвата просто регулярное выражение, например такое `\-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E[\-\+]\d{2})?)?`, вот можно [проверить его онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/6WxMDU/2). Просто проитерировать по множественному захвату этой регуляркой.

Вот полный код на Java, также [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NBeB/4):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "0.0-2.013896591961E-04-1.136868377216E-12 12 22 44";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+(?:E[\\-\\+]\\d{2})?)?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(group);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо:)

Comment: @МаксимСавельев Конечно я это сделал регулярку только на основе 5 чисел из примера, но кто его знает какие там в файле варианты ещё будут, скорее всего нужно будет ещё отлаживать регулярку пока весь файл не удастся захватить.

Comment: в строке могут быть целые числа типа "12 22 44" и вот тут думаю надо проверять содержит ли цифра e. предварительно разделив split строку по пробелам

Comment: @МаксимСавельев Можно целые числа и дробные также одной регуляркой общей захватывать, достаточно её немного поправить вот так `\-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E[\-\+]\d{2})?)?`

Comment: @МаксимСавельев Просто проверять на наличие E в записе числа не достаточно, т.к. числа дробные могут без E быть например `0.0` из примера.